# Calculating two LM in one plot using stat_poly_eq

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I have calculated linear regression models between soil acetone emission and soil carbon content and plotted this in a graph like this:

[image]

Instead of showing one regression model in the plots I would like to show one for organic and one for mineral soil in the same plot. E.g. with different colours.

Any ideas?
All help is much appreciated!

Here's the code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

 formula <- y~x

(p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(carbon, acetone)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula = formula, col="black") +
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap(~days)+
    stat_poly_eq(
      aes(label = paste(stat(adj.rr.label), stat(p.value.label), sep = "*\", \"*")),
      formula = formula, rr.digits = 1, p.digits = 1, parse = TRUE,size=3.5))
```

Here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(carbon = c(22, 19, 21, 3, 45, 25, 24, 72, 1, 63, 
13, 69, 6, 4, 11, 8, 8, 9, 9, 5, 164, 17, 8, 4, 2, 7, 1, 14, 
88, 16, 1, 115, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 80, 29, 5, 8, 1, 2, 4, 17, 
19, 7, 22, 19, 21, 3, 45, 25, 1, 63, 13, 69, 6, 4, 11, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 5, 16, 17, 8, 4, 2, 7, 1, 14, 88, 16, 1, 115, 4, 4, 3, 
2, 1, 2, 80, 296, 5, 8, 1, 17, 19, 7), acetone = c(12, 12, 8, 
17, 60, 260, 65, 171, 0, 30, 13, 0, 56, 3619, 
200, 20, 448, 242, 175, 265, 9, 19, 23, 14, 30, 162, 
16, 299, 0, 0, 120, 17, 307, 57, 0, 8, 4, 44, 98, 2, 
10, 385, 91, 130, 21, 12, 65, 181, 3, 5, 0, 44, 24, 11, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 531, 0, 0, 2, 30, 4, 2, 29, 12, 0, 87, 13, 0, 0, 
0, 105, 155, 198, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 50, 0, 31, 0, 0, 
126, 70, 0), days = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 
94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 
94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 
94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L), soil_type = c("organic", "mineral", 
"organic", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", 
"mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"organic", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", 
"mineral", "organic", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", 
"organic", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", 
"mineral", "organic", "mineral", "organic", "mineral", "mineral"
)), row.names = c(NA, -92L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, thanks for editing my question! How did you visualize the image?

Comment: Does it suffice to add  `fill = soil_type` to your main aes call?   i.e. `(p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(carbon, acetone,  fill = soil_type)) + `...

Comment: Yes that is perfect, thanks @Jon Spring!

Comment: You forget to end the code block after `dput`, the image link was inside it. I just completed the code bloack.